# Where are default atom packages?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm looking to remove/modify the autocomplete-plus package that is bundled together with atom on install.

After a while of struggling and failing, I come to the wisdom of stack-overflow for how I can either:

1. Modify behaviour of autocomplete-plus
2. prevent it from loading in the first place (i.e. remove it from the bundle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default packages are stored inside an [asar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asar) file (i.e. `Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar` on macOS), so it's highly impractical to tamper with its contents, not to mention that your changes are getting lost with each Atom update.

Since you haven't given us a reason why you would want to do that, there is no ideal answer to your question. Generally speaking, I think there are better alternatives:

1. Disable the `autocomplete-plus` package and install your fork as you would install any other package. The Atom API offers ways to [disable packages](https://atom.io/docs/api/latest/PackageManager#instance-disablePackage) programmatically, if you want your fork to handle this.
2. [Build](https://github.com/atom/atom#building) your own custom version of Atom that suits your needs. The default packages are listed as `packageDependencies` in [`package.json`](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/v1.14.3/package.json#L92).

Answer (score 0):

You can go to edit->preferences in the main menu, then check under 'packages' in the left-hand menu, search for 'autocomplete-plus' and then click on 'disable.

Comment: I'd prefer to remove the folder (if it exists locally), and replace it with a modified one. I'm currently experiencing name collisions (i think), and my custom one is being ignored because of the one packaged with atom.